# How to fit image in div container?

Tags: html, css

I have image `<img>` in `<div>` container.

```
<div id="container">
    <img id="image" />
</div>
```

Images can be different sizes and the container size is **fixed**. I want to fit image fully in the container, centered, without stretching and **without using this image as css background of the `<div>`** as most of the stack overflow answers suggest. [Here is the js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dimetriusifua/bcmy4yn6/) of what I've already tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
.container {
    margin: 20px;

    width: 100px;
    height: 120px;
    position:relative; 
    border: 1px solid red;  
}

.container img {
    max-width:100%;
    max-height:100%;
    position:absolute; 
    top:50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%);
}
```

Here's the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bcmy4yn6/10/)

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
.container {
    margin: 20px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 120px;
    text-align:center;
    border: 1px solid red;    
}

.container img {
    width:auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    max-height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

I've made you a [working fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/bcmy4yn6/11/) with your code.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with imnancysun. However, you should add the vendor prefixes to make sure the css will work with more browsers. I would suggest:

```
.container {
    margin: 20px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 120px;
    position:relative; 
    border: 1px solid red;  
}

.container img {
    max-width:100%;
    max-height:100%;
    position:absolute; 
    top:50%;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%);
        -ms-transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%);
            transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%);
}
```

I use firefox most of the time. Without the prefixes, all of the images where outside of the divs.

[This](http://pleeease.io/play/) is a cool tool to help add the vendor prefixes to your CSS.